# How do I add icons on the desktop?

Tags: release-hera

How do I add icons on the desktop, such as the Trash, Documents, and Home icons?

I am using Elementary Hera  5.1.5.

Answer (score 0):

elementary OS è progettato proprio per non avere icone sul desktop, è una filosofia loro. Ti consiglio di cambiare distribuzione onde evitare di perdere tempo per far funzionare una cosa che magari ne rompe altre tre. ;)

Comment: Grazie infinite...

Answer (score 0):

You could install desktop folder from the AppCenter

Answer (score 0):

You could install desktop folder from the AppCenter or from a .deb file which wil be available onine.